# Original Battlefront will not start on Xbox 360?

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360, star-wars-battlefront

I have purchased Star Wars Battlefront (2004) on the Xbox store for my 360. When I click on the game it gives me an error message and sends me back to the homepage. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the game, I have a hard drive, and S.W.B. is listed under the Original Xbox games that will play on the 360.

What can I do to fix this error? This picture isn't mine but its the same error:

[image: The game couldn't start. Try downloading the game again]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an article on the official Xbox 360 support site for the “The game could not start” error, which can be found at https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/errors/game-could-not-start

Relevant info copied (links can be found on the original article):

> If this error occurs when playing an Xbox original game
>
> If this problem occurs when you try to play an original Xbox game, try the following solutions:
>
> #### Solution 1: Update your console software
>
> Make sure your console has the latest software update.
>
> #### Solution 2: Make sure that you have an official Xbox 360 Hard Drive
>
> You can play most original Xbox games on your Xbox 360 console if you have an official Xbox 360 Hard Drive and the latest console software. If you have the latest console software and an official Xbox 360 Hard Drive but you get the “Game could not start” error, the game is probably not supported by Xbox 360.
>
> #### Solution 3: Try cleaning the game disc
>
> For information about how to clean discs, see [Care for your console and game discs.](https://support.xbox.com/xbox-360/system/care-maintain)
>
> #### Solution 4: Try a different Xbox 360 Hard Drive
>
> To see if the problem is related to your console's hard drive, try using a different official Xbox 360 Hard Drive to play the game (if you have access to one).
>
> If the game works with a different hard drive or on a different Xbox 360 console, your Xbox 360 Hard Drive may need to be replaced.
>
> #### Solution 5: Request a replacement hard drive
>
> If the solutions above didn’t resolve the problem, go to the Online Service Center and click Replace an Accessory under Devices to order a replacement hard drive.

Comment: minus buying a replacement hard drive, which i don't have the money for. this didn't fix my problem. though I suppose that is the next step in figuring this out. thank you.

Comment: i did not give you the bounty, but i hope what i did do will suffice. thank you for your help.